# controlled conversion of int to char and print them

Tags: c, list, for-loop, matrix, type-conversion

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SPN 5
#define BTT 10 
#define MARKER 'X'



void create_pirolito(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);
void create_retardado(int list[BTT]);
void compare(int matriz[SPN][SPN], int list[BTT]);
void print_list(int list[BTT]);
void print_matriz(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);


// create matriz
void create_pirolito(int matriz[SPN][SPN])
{
    for(int i=0; i<SPN; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
        {
            matriz[i][j]=rand()%25;
        }
    }
}


// create list
void create_retardado(int list[BTT])
{
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
        list[i]=rand()%20;
    }
}




int main()
{
    int pirolito[SPN][SPN];
    int retardado[BTT];
    int z=0;
    const char *normal = "%2d";
    const char *duplicate = "%2c";
    
    create_pirolito(pirolito);
    create_retardado(retardado);
    
    while(z<100)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
            {
                for(int n=0; n<SPN; n++)
                {
                    if(pirolito[j][n]==retardado[i])
                    {
                        pirolito[j][n]=MARKER;
                        printf("|");
                        printf(duplicate, pirolito[j][n]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("|");
                        printf(normal, pirolito[j][n]);
                    }
                }
                printf("|\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
            printf(" e o numero escolhido e: %2d", retardado[i]);
            getchar();
        }
        z++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The function of this code is to create an array and a list in its respective functions, in the main the program with the int i accesses the number of the respective index i of the list(retardado) and scrolls through the matrix(pirolito) all the demand for equality, when found, the int of the matrix is exchanged by int 88 and printed with the Char X but the problem is when the int i changes the new impression of the matrix does not come with the X in the previous number and yes the 88. The idea and the matrix the new one presents not only the X in the actual number but also in all the ones prior to this. Like this:

| 1|11| 2|15|18|
| X|11|17|24|21|
|12| 2|15| 9|13|
| 1|15| 1|22|11|
|11|18|17| 4| 7|

e o numero escolhido e: 10
the number 10 is X

before getchar():

| 1| X| 2|15|18|
| X| X|17|24|21|
|12| 2|15| 9|13|
| 1|15| 1|22| X|
| X|18|17| 4| 7|

e o numero escolhido e: 11
the number 11 and 10 is X

AND NOT:

| 1| X| 2|15|18|
|88| X|17|24|21|
|12| 2|15| 9|13|
| 1|15| 1|22| X|
| X|18|17| 4| 7|

e o numero escolhido e: 11
the number 10 is now 88 not X

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra check in your if statement to see if the matrix cell already has an 'X'. If it does, print it as a char and not an int.

```
if (pirolito[j][n] == 'X' || 
    pirolito[j][n] == retardado[i])
```

Comment: Never use values like `88` to represent `'X'` in code.  Just use `'X'`.

Comment: Changed, thanks. I had a "magic number".